# DataFrame GroupBy into VolumeBars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I need to consolidate market data into VolumeBars (Blocks with same Volume).

As input data I have minute bars (possible with drops), where I have following columns: Time, OHLC (Open, High, Low, Close) and Volume.

Currently, I'm trying this way:

```
bar_volume_size = 100
df = hg
df['cumsum'] = (df["Volume"].cumsum() // bar_volume_size) + 1
df['over'] = (df["Volume"].cumsum() % bar_volume_size)
print(df.head(40))
```

Results of this operation looks like this:

```
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume  BarNo  over
2018-12-30 18:00:00  2.6780  2.6875  2.6755  2.6840      83      1    83
2018-12-30 18:01:00  2.6835  2.6875  2.6825  2.6875      40      2    23
2018-12-30 18:02:00  2.6875  2.6920  2.6875  2.6915      58      2    81
2018-12-30 18:03:00  2.6915  2.6945  2.6910  2.6920      36      3    17
2018-12-30 18:04:00  2.6910  2.6925  2.6910  2.6920      14      3    31
2018-12-30 18:05:00  2.6920  2.6920  2.6900  2.6900      16      3    47
2018-12-30 18:06:00  2.6905  2.6905  2.6880  2.6880      12      3    59
2018-12-30 18:07:00  2.6885  2.6890  2.6880  2.6880       5      3    64
2018-12-30 18:08:00  2.6885  2.6885  2.6880  2.6885       3      3    67
2018-12-30 18:09:00  2.6875  2.6875  2.6875  2.6875       1      3    68
2018-12-30 18:10:00  2.6875  2.6890  2.6875  2.6890       9      3    77
2018-12-30 18:11:00  2.6895  2.6895  2.6895  2.6895       4      3    81
2018-12-30 18:12:00  2.6900  2.6900  2.6890  2.6895      13      3    94
2018-12-30 18:13:00  2.6895  2.6895  2.6890  2.6890       3      3    97
2018-12-30 18:14:00  2.6890  2.6895  2.6890  2.6895      10      4     7
2018-12-30 18:15:00  2.6895  2.6895  2.6895  2.6895       0      4     7
2018-12-30 18:16:00  2.6895  2.6900  2.6895  2.6900       4      4    11
2018-12-30 18:17:00  2.6890  2.6895  2.6855  2.6870      31      4    42
2018-12-30 18:18:00  2.6875  2.6875  2.6875  2.6875       8      4    50
2018-12-30 18:19:00  2.6875  2.6885  2.6875  2.6885       5      4    55
2018-12-30 18:20:00  2.6890  2.6905  2.6890  2.6905       4      4    59
2018-12-30 18:21:00  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910       2      4    61
2018-12-30 18:22:00  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910       0      4    61
2018-12-30 18:23:00  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910       0      4    61
2018-12-30 18:24:00  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910  2.6910       0      4    61
2018-12-30 18:25:00  2.6905  2.6905  2.6905  2.6905       1      4    62
2018-12-30 18:26:00  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890       1      4    63
2018-12-30 18:27:00  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890       1      4    64
2018-12-30 18:28:00  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890       2      4    66
2018-12-30 18:29:00  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890       0      4    66
2018-12-30 18:30:00  2.6895  2.6900  2.6890  2.6890       6      4    72
2018-12-30 18:31:00  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890       1      4    73
2018-12-30 18:32:00  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890  2.6890       0      4    73
2018-12-30 18:33:00  2.6900  2.6900  2.6865  2.6890      14      4    87
2018-12-30 18:34:00  2.6870  2.6870  2.6865  2.6865      10      4    97
2018-12-30 18:35:00  2.6865  2.6865  2.6865  2.6865       0      4    97
2018-12-30 18:36:00  2.6860  2.6860  2.6850  2.6860      21      5    18
2018-12-30 18:37:00  2.6870  2.6875  2.6870  2.6875       4      5    22
2018-12-30 18:38:00  2.6865  2.6865  2.6865  2.6865       1      5    23
2018-12-30 18:39:00  2.6865  2.6865  2.6865  2.6865       1      5    24
```

In the BarNo column I have VolumeBar number. I think that this is possible to GroupBy dataframe with BarNo column, for example for 3:

```
                       Open    High     Low   Close  Volume  BarNo  over
2018-12-30 18:03:00  2.6915  2.6945  2.6910  2.6920      36      3    17
2018-12-30 18:04:00  2.6910  2.6925  2.6910  2.6920      14      3    31
2018-12-30 18:05:00  2.6920  2.6920  2.6900  2.6900      16      3    47
2018-12-30 18:06:00  2.6905  2.6905  2.6880  2.6880      12      3    59
2018-12-30 18:07:00  2.6885  2.6890  2.6880  2.6880       5      3    64
2018-12-30 18:08:00  2.6885  2.6885  2.6880  2.6885       3      3    67
2018-12-30 18:09:00  2.6875  2.6875  2.6875  2.6875       1      3    68
2018-12-30 18:10:00  2.6875  2.6890  2.6875  2.6890       9      3    77
2018-12-30 18:11:00  2.6895  2.6895  2.6895  2.6895       4      3    81
2018-12-30 18:12:00  2.6900  2.6900  2.6890  2.6895      13      3    94
2018-12-30 18:13:00  2.6895  2.6895  2.6890  2.6890       3      3    97
```

Take first element from "Open" column of this group, max of the "High" column of this group, min of the "Low" column of this group and last element of the "Close" column, take exactly `bar_volume_size` as "Volume" and put all this data into another DataFrame (or, maybe in this dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby with aggregation like this.

```
group_rules = {'Open':'first', 'High':'max', 'Low':'min'}
df.groupby(['BarNo']).agg(group_rules).reset_index()
```

Comment: Awesome! Almost what I need!

Comment: Great. You can upvote and mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: Not sure how to, I have not enough reputation to upvote you